# Why is this not printing my list on a single line?

Tags: python, list

I wrote a program that takes in a number and produces a sequence, which is indexed into a list. Now I want to print the list in a continuous manner (rather than having it print each index on the next line). For some unknown reason to me, what I wrote is not working.

Here is my code:

```
x=int(input())
z=x
iz=x
l=[]

i=1
while i < 11:
    z = x+x*(i-1)
    while z >= 100:
        z = z%100
    iz = x*(x**(i-1))
    while iz>=100:
        iz = iz%100
    l.append(z)
    l.append(iz)
    i+=1

for j in range(10):
    print(l[j], end=" ")
```

Comment: I entered `5` and it printed `5 5 10 25 15 25 20 25 25 25`

Comment: Try printing an empty line after the loop is done.

Comment: Output is buffered, so nothing gets written until you write a newline. And when the script ends, the output will be on the same line as the shell prompt.

Comment: Add a `print()` call following the final `for` loop's code to see the result..

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Old answer deleted, as OP changed question code.

Current version as it is posted is working as intended:

```
x=int(input())
z=x
iz=x
l=[]

i=1
while i < 11:
    z = x+x*(i-1)
    while z >= 100:
        z = z%100
    iz = x*(x**(i-1))
    while iz>=100:
        iz = iz%100
    l.append(z)
    l.append(iz)
    i+=1

for j in range(10):
    print(l[j], end=" ")
```

**Note that if you press F5 to start your code you need to enter a number in the console and press enter to start.**

Consider changing your first line to

```
x=int(input("Enter Number: "))
```

To show that something changed and give a visual hint that the program started.

Input: `5`

Output: `5 5 10 25 15 25 20 25 25 25`

Comment: Those were apparently copying errors, he's already changed the question.

Comment: In that case the edited version works though without edits, input `5` results in `5 5 10 25 15 25 20 25 25 25 `

Comment: nope, i forgot to change the vriables when psting that was not the thing that was causing the issue

Comment: @user844179 Using your code as you posted it works. What is happening on your end that you still have an issue?

Comment: it just doesn't print anything, it runs and thats it

Comment: @user844179 Did you enter a number and confirm with enter?

Comment: I have figured it out, I used the python console to run my code (with time imported so it stays on screen longer), for some reason it decided that it doesn't want to print. in short, I ran the program through command line and it works there perfectly, thank you very much to everyone that helped

Comment: Glad to hear you managed to figure it out.